# Four similar triangles

Tags: geometry, triangle

The challenge as described hereafter is to create a total of 4 similar triangles by drawing 4 triangle in a scalene, acute triangle - out of the 5 resulting triangles (4 that make the original one)

If D, E, and F are the middle of the sides of the triangle ABC than the 4 triangles created are equivalent and with the original triangle we get 5 similar triangles.

[image]

The challenge: 
In a triangle create four internal triangles as described in the following diagram. The requirement is that with the original triangle you get exactly FOUR similar triangles.

[image]

What is unique about the internal triangle KJL? What is unique about the points on the sides, K, J, and L?

Comment: How are there 4 similar triangles in the bottom picture? I don't even see 2 similar triangles

Comment: KL||HG, jk||GI, JL||HI

Comment: @Himanshu that's not true. that is only the case if youmake the triangles like the top picture.

Comment: Please note that the questions are only for the second case. The first case is trivial and well investigate.

Comment: Points K, J, L lie on the angle bisectors of the triangle GIH.

Comment: I don't think that you can prove that the result is 4 similar triangle - actually it is not correct!

Comment: Can you clarify which are the similar triangles in the second case? I'm guessing they're the four that are NOT the central triangle (GHI, HJK, IKL, GJL) but want to make sure.

Comment: Actually I state it in a general way to "enhance" the quality of the puzzle. The triangle JKL will not be similar to the other three internal and the original HGI (total 4) triangles. This could be derived easily from the need to have the HGI angels participating in the "similarity".

Answer (score 2):

In order to create four similar triangles instead of five, it is necessary to:

> 1. **reflect two of the internal triangles** (refer to examples below)
>
>  2. and place the third, non-reflected, internal triangle inside any vertex - provided this vertex has an angle less than $90^\circ$. Call this internal angle $\alpha$.
>
>  3. then form the base of an $isosceles$ triangle with the internal side of the non-reflected triangle
>
>  4. then use two equal lengths of the two reflected triangles and two angles equal to $\alpha$ to complete the internal, $isosceles$ triangle

The internal triangle KJL is unique because it is:

> **an isosceles triangle**.  Points J, K, L are unique as determined by the requirement to form an $isosceles$ triangle with 2 angles equal to $\alpha$.

Examples of obtuse and acute triangles with several placements of the internal triangles:

> [image: Triangles]

Comment: The claims are not correct. This is not a solution. I tried your claim using Geogebra and found easily cases when this is not working. You need to try in another way. The right solution will work for any scalene and acute triangle.

Comment: @Moti - OK, I think this is a better answer.

Comment: Let me look at this in details. It could be correct!

Comment: It has to be "scalene, acute triangle". So the $100^0$ is not a good example to start with.

Comment: How exactly the reflection is carried out? Trial and error?

Comment: Though I was expecting a different solution, your solution is correct but requires proof to be complete. The drawings demonstrate that a solution exist.

Comment: Moti - The requirement for a proof was not in original question. As I am not a math person, I cannot do this. Maybe @JoeZ. would be interested or you could just provide your own answer.

Comment: Usually, an answer like this requires the proof since there might be a case were a solution may fail. Could you at least provide a clear way how to do the reflection which is key for your solution. How you select this point around which you reflect? I will try to seek a solution.

Comment: Who is JoeZ? Could you elaborate?